# $x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ is not locally lipschitz at $x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In order to show $x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ is not globally Lipschitz I can say that

$\frac{u^{\frac{2}{3}}-0}{u-0} \rightarrow\infty$  as $u \rightarrow 0$

However, why does this tell me that $x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ is not locally lipschitz at $x=0$?

Comment: Because the difference quotient is not bounded, as you wrote. Lipschitz is equivalent to a bound on the difference quotient.

Comment: I understand what I have written above implies  $x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ is not globally Lipschitz. But why does it imply that it is not locally lipschitz at $x=0$?

Comment: @usainlightning Because no matter how you bound $u$, there will be no Lipschitz constant $C$ such that
$$|u^{\frac23} - 0| \le C|u-0| \quad\forall\ |u|\le \epsilon$$
For any $\epsilon > 0$. If the function is locally Lipschitz at $0$, such an $\epsilon$ and a $C$ must exist.

Comment: Because the singularity is at $u→0$. Every neighborhood of $0$ contains $0$ and thus the singularity. This is what locally Lipschitz means, there is a neighborhood, usually bounded, where there is a bound on the difference quotient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function $f(u)=|u|^{2/3}$ were locally Lipschitz at $u=0$, then there would have to exist some $ϵ>0$ and some constant $C>0$ so that, among other inequalities,
$$
||u|^{2/3}−0|≤C|u−0|
$$
for all $u\in(-ϵ,ϵ)$.

Clearly, your computations show that this is not possible, however small you choose $ϵ$, the singularity at $u=0$ is still contained in $(-ϵ,ϵ)$ and thus the difference quotients are unbounded.